# Return a single object after Observable is complete

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable

I have an Observable with a couple of elements (fonts)

```
myFontsObservable = Observable.of<Font>(new Font("font1"), new Font("font2"));
```

Now I want to subscribe this Observable, process all the Fonts and register them in a Document and just after it finishes processing all of them, return the Document

```
public registerFonts(myFontsObservable): Observable<Document> {
    doc = new Document();
    myFontsObservable.subscribe(
        font => doc.register(font);
        (err) => {},
        () => return Observable.of(doc);
    );
    // I need to return something here too
}
```

This code won't compile because I need to return something also outside the subscribe. But if I return something there then when I call registerFonts(...) I get the wrong value because it is not yet complete

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try something along these lines

```
public registerFonts(myFontsObservable): Observable<Document> {
    return myFontsObservable
           .reduce((doc, font) => {
              doc.register(font);
              return doc
           }, new Document())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the mergeMap operator (pipeable).

This operator will process the result of the first observable,, and needs to return another observable. I believe this is what you need.

```
public registerFonts(myFontsObservable): Observable<Document> {
    doc = new Document();
    return myFontsObservable.pipe(
      mergeMap(font => {
        doc.register(font);
        return Observable.of(doc);
      })
    );
}
```

Comment: If you do like this, you emit 2 times the Document: the first time after the first font has been registered, the second time after the second font has been registered.

Comment: I don't know how he calls it, but in any way you're wrong : it returns 2 different documents, not 2 times the same document. But I get your point. What's the purpose there ? I thought he only needed to write a correct function, but it seems that it's not that ...

Comment: I am not sure it is always a different document. `doc` refers always to the same object created in the first line of the function.

Comment: And if the function is called 2 times, the `doc` is created 2 times. Isn't the function called 2 times ? That's not clear at all for me right now ...